RuntimeError: Expected target size [20, 2], got [20]
I am Getting Error while running the below code can anyone help me to find out the problem what i am doing wrong in the code I am new to pytorch so give me little details information about the error.
class Classifier(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.MFB = MFB(512,768,True,256,64,0.1)
    self.fin_y_shape = torch.nn.Linear(768,512)
    self.fin_old = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin = torch.nn.Linear(16 * 768, 64)
    self.fin_inten = torch.nn.Linear(64,6)
    self.fin_e1 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e2 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e3 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e4 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e5 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e6 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e7 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e8 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)
    self.fin_e9 = torch.nn.Linear(64,2)



    self.validation_step_outputs = []
    self.test_step_outputs = []

  def forward(self, x,y,rag):
      x_,y_,rag_ = x,y,rag
      print("x.shape", x.shape)
      z = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1), torch.unsqueeze(x, axis=1))
      z_rag = self.MFB(torch.unsqueeze(y, axis=1), torch.unsqueeze(rag, axis=1))
      z_newe = torch.cat((z, z_rag), dim=1)

      z_new = torch.squeeze(z_newe, dim=1)
      c_inten = self.fin_inten(z_new)
      c_e1 = self.fin_e1(z_new)
      c_e2 = self.fin_e2(z_new)
      c_e3 = self.fin_e3(z_new)
      c_e4 = self.fin_e4(z_new)
      c_e5 = self.fin_e5(z_new)
      c_e6 = self.fin_e6(z_new)
      c_e7 = self.fin_e7(z_new)
      c_e8 = self.fin_e8(z_new)
      c_e9 = self.fin_e9(z_new)
      c = self.fin_old(z_new)


      output = torch.log_softmax(c, dim=1)
      c_inten = torch.log_softmax(c_inten, dim=1)
      c_e1 = torch.log_softmax(c_e1, dim=1)
      c_e2 = torch.log_softmax(c_e2, dim=1)
      c_e3 = torch.log_softmax(c_e3, dim=1)
      c_e4 = torch.log_softmax(c_e4, dim=1)
      c_e5 = torch.log_softmax(c_e5, dim=1)
      c_e6 = torch.log_softmax(c_e6, dim=1)
      c_e7 = torch.log_softmax(c_e7, dim=1)
      c_e8 = torch.log_softmax(c_e8, dim=1)
      c_e9 = torch.log_softmax(c_e9, dim=1)
   I am Getting Error while running the below code can anyone help me to find out the problem what i am doing wrong in the code I am new to pytorch so give me little details information about the error.

   return output,c_inten,c_e1,c_e2,c_e3,c_e4,c_e5,c_e6,c_e7,c_e8,c_e9



  def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
    return F.nll_loss(logits, labels)

  def contrastive_loss(self, z, z_rag, label, margin=1.0):
    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(z1, z2)
    loss_contrastive = torch.mean((1 - label) * torch.pow(euclidean_distance, 2) + (label) * torch.pow(torch.clamp(margin - euclidean_distance, min=0.0), 2))
    return loss_contrastive

  def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
      
      lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9 = train_batch
      lab = train_batch[lab]
      #print(lab)
      txt = train_batch[txt]
      rag = train_batch[rag]
      img = train_batch[img]
      name= train_batch[name]
      intensity = train_batch[intensity]
      e1 = train_batch[e1]
      e2 = train_batch[e2]
      e3 = train_batch[e3]
      e4 = train_batch[e4]
      e5 = train_batch[e5]
      e6 = train_batch[e6]
      e7 = train_batch[e7]
      e8 = train_batch[e8]
      e9 = train_batch[e9]

      logit_offen,logit_inten_target,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)

      loss1 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_offen, lab)
      loss4 = self.cross_entropy_loss(a, e1)
      loss5 = self.cross_entropy_loss(b, e2)
      loss6 = self.cross_entropy_loss(c, e3)
      loss7 = self.cross_entropy_loss(d, e4)
      loss8 = self.cross_entropy_loss(e, e5)
      loss9 = self.cross_entropy_loss(f, e6)
      loss10 = self.cross_entropy_loss(g, e7)
      loss11 = self.cross_entropy_loss(h, e8)
      loss12 = self.cross_entropy_loss(i, e9)
      loss17 = self.cross_entropy_loss(logit_inten_target, intensity)

      contrastive_labels = (lab == 1).float()
      loss_contrastive = self.contrastive_loss(z, z_rag, contrastive_labels)

      loss = loss1 + loss4 + loss5 + loss6 + loss7 + loss8 +loss9 + loss10 + loss11 + loss12 + loss17 + loss_contrastive

      self.log('train_loss', loss)
      return loss

  def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx):
      #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp = val_batch
      lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= val_batch
      lab = val_batch[lab]
      #print(lab)
      txt = val_batch[txt]
      rag = val_batch[rag]
      img = val_batch[img]
      name = val_batch[name]
      intensity = val_batch[intensity]
      e1 = val_batch[e1]
      e2 = val_batch[e2]
      e3 = val_batch[e3]
      e4 = val_batch[e4]
      e5 = val_batch[e5]
      e6 = val_batch[e6]
      e7 = val_batch[e7]
      e8 = val_batch[e8]
      e9 = val_batch[e9]

      logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = self.forward(txt,img,rag)


      logits=logits.float()


      tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(),axis=1)
      loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
      lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
      self.log('val_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
      self.log('val_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
      self.log('val_loss', loss)
      tqdm_dict = {'val_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
      self.validation_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})

      return {
                'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
      'val_f1 offensive': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
      }

  def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
    outs = []
    outs14=[]
    for out in self.validation_step_outputs:
       outs.append(out['progress_bar']['val_acc'])
       outs14.append(out['val_f1 offensive'])
    self.log('val_acc_all_offn', sum(outs)/len(outs))
    self.log('val_f1 offensive', sum(outs14)/len(outs14))
    print(f'***val_acc_all_offn at epoch end {sum(outs)/len(outs)}****')
    print(f'***val_f1 offensive at epoch end {sum(outs14)/len(outs14)}****')
    self.validation_step_outputs.clear()

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
      lab,txt,rag,img,name,intensity,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9= batch
      #lab,txt,rag,img,name,per,iro,alli,ana,inv,meta,puns,sat,hyp= batch

      lab = batch[lab]
      #print(lab)


      txt = batch[txt]
      rag = batch[rag]
      img = batch[img]
      name = batch[name]
      intensity = batch[intensity]
      e1 = batch[e1]
      e2 = batch[e2]
      e3 = batch[e3]
      e4 = batch[e4]
      e5 = batch[e5]
      e6 = batch[e6]
      e7 = batch[e7]
      e8 = batch[e8]
      e9 = batch[e9]

      logits,inten,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i= self.forward(txt,img,rag)
      logits = logits.float()
      tmp = np.argmax(logits.detach().cpu().numpy(force=True),axis=-1)
      loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, lab)
      lab = lab.detach().cpu().numpy()
      self.log('test_acc', accuracy_score(lab,tmp))
      self.log('test_roc_auc',roc_auc_score(lab,tmp))
      self.log('test_loss', loss)
      tqdm_dict = {'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp)}
      self.test_step_outputs.append({'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp), 'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')})
      return {
                'progress_bar': tqdm_dict,
                'test_acc': accuracy_score(lab,tmp),
                'test_f1_score': f1_score(lab,tmp,average='macro')
      }
  def on_test_epoch_end(self):
      # OPTIONAL
      outs = []
      outs1,outs2,outs3,outs4,outs5,outs6,outs7,outs8,outs9,outs10,outs11,outs12,outs13,outs14 = \
      [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
      for out in self.test_step_outputs:
        outs.append(out['test_acc'])
        outs2.append(out['test_f1_score'])
      self.log('test_acc', sum(outs)/len(outs))
      self.log('test_f1_score', sum(outs2)/len(outs2))
      self.test_step_outputs.clear()

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    # optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=3e-2)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

    return optimizer


"""
Main Model:
Initialize
Forward Pass
Training Step
Validation Step
Testing Step

Pp
"""

class HmDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):

  def setup(self, stage):
    self.hm_train = t_p
    self.hm_val = v_p
    # self.hm_test = test
    self.hm_test = te_p

  def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.hm_train, batch_size=20, drop_last=True)

  def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.hm_val, batch_size=20, drop_last=True)

  def test_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.hm_test, batch_size=20, drop_last=True)

data_module = HmDataModule()
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
     monitor='val_acc_all_offn',
     dirpath='mrinal/',
     filename='epoch{epoch:02d}-val_f1_all_offn{val_acc_all_offn:.2f}',
     auto_insert_metric_name=False,
     save_top_k=1,
    mode="max",
 )
all_callbacks = []
all_callbacks.append(checkpoint_callback)
# train
from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything
seed_everything(42, workers=True)
hm_model = Classifier()
gpus=1
#if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=20,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

INFO:lightning_fabric.utilities.seed:Seed set to 42
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:Using bfloat16 Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP)
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:GPU available: False, used: False
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.utilities.rank_zero:HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs
INFO:pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary:
   | Name        | Type   | Params
----------------------------------------
0  | MFB         | MFB    | 21.0 M
1  | fin_y_shape | Linear | 393 K 
2  | fin_old     | Linear | 130   
3  | fin         | Linear | 786 K 
4  | fin_inten   | Linear | 390   
5  | fin_e1      | Linear | 130   
6  | fin_e2      | Linear | 130   
7  | fin_e3      | Linear | 130   
8  | fin_e4      | Linear | 130   
9  | fin_e5      | Linear | 130   
10 | fin_e6      | Linear | 130   
11 | fin_e7      | Linear | 130   
12 | fin_e8      | Linear | 130   
13 | fin_e9      | Linear | 130   
----------------------------------------
22.2 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
22.2 M    Total params
88.745    Total estimated model params size (MB)
x.shape torch.Size([20, 768])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-c76eb94fa135> in <cell line: 266>()
    264 #if torch.cuda.is_available():gpus=0
    265 trainer = pl.Trainer(deterministic=True,max_epochs=20,precision=16,callbacks=all_callbacks)
--> 266 trainer.fit(hm_model, data_module)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2702     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2703         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2704     return torch._C._nn.nll_loss_nd(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2705 
   2706 

RuntimeError: Expected target size [20, 2], got [20]
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0%
 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]


I am Getting error in that where I am doing Mistake can Anyone help me solve the issue.
I am Getting Error while running the below code can anyone help me to find out the problem what i am doing wrong in the code I am new to pytorch so give me little details information about the error.

You probably need to output two probability values if you have two classes, not one.

can you please give more explanation in which part of code I have to do modification

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
